# Error in Google BigQuery <EOF>

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-visualization

I am new to Google BigQuery. I need help with the query error:

> "Encountered " "WITH" "with "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting:
>   EOF"

```
with
  t1 as 
  (
    select
    date(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(event_dim.timestamp_micros)) date, event_dim.name
    from
    [myfoody-1313:it_rawfish_myfoody_ANDROID.app_events_20160727]
    where
    event_dim.name='pv_detail' and event_dim.params.key='item_id' and
    event_dim.params.value.string_value='31'
  )
  select
  date(d) as day, count(event_dim.name)
from
  generate_series(current_date - interval '6 day', current_date, '1 day') d
  left join t1 on t1.date = d
group by day
order by day;
```

Comment: After you enable standard SQL using Mikhail's suggestion below, there are a couple of other transformations you will need to make to your query, namely:

* Use `CAST(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_dim.timestamp_micros) AS DATE)`.
* Use an explicit array instead of `GENERATE_SERIES`. I filed a feature request for series/array generation here, which would fill this gap: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=646

Comment: As an update, `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` is now available in BigQuery. in the query above, for instance, you could use `FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS d LEFT JOIN ...`.

Answer (score 14):

> I need help on a query error: "Encountered " "WITH" "with "" at line
>   1, column 1. Was expecting: EOF"

WITH is supported for BigQuery Standard SQL - see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) - you should enable Standard SQL

Answer (score 3):

Under **Show Options** uncheck **Use Legacy Sql**

Answer (score 1):

To access BQ using Terminal command:

For Ignoring these cases: "Encountered", "WITH", "with" at line 1, column 1. "Was expecting: EOF"

Use: `--use_legacy_sql=false`

Normal Query example from the terminal:

```sh
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * from `table_name` where published_date >= "2020-05-05" limit 10;'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running

```
self.hook.run_query(sql=sql_query)
```

from the Airflow [BigQuery Hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery.BigQueryHook.run_query) where I had a further error message compared to the one posted in the question:

```
Was expecting:
    <EOF>
[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]
```

According to the 1st doc I mentioned:

> use_legacy_sql (bool | None) – Whether to use legacy SQL (true) or standard SQL (false). If None, defaults to self.use_legacy_sql.

So I changed it to:

```
self.hook.run_query(sql=sql_query, use_legacy_sql=False)
```

and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We also getting the same exception while running the query via Java SDK, to fix it we passed table name like `` `project_id.dataset_id.table` ``

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is wrong so i fix that and try #standardsql while writing any query, in this way you don't need to do any setting changes. Try below code and add in ur whole query.

## standardSQL

with
  t1 as 
  (
    select
    date((current_timestamp())) date, 
    'xyz' name
--     from

--     where
--     event_dim.name='pv_detail' and event_dim.params.key='item_id' and
--     event_dim.params.value.string_value='31'
  )

select 
  cast(d as date) day,
  count(name)
from  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 day), date_sub(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 day))) d
  left join t1 on t1.date = cast(d as date)
group by 1
order by 1;